# How to install QQ on wine 5?

Tags: wine

Why I did it:I was using deepin-qq, but it cannot download group files and a QQ update rendered it unusable.(something about needing to update to a new version?)

What I did:I installed wine5 and tried to use `wine5 PCQQ2020.exe`, it ran through the installation but gave a black screen when it came to opening QQ.

What I tried:

- search google and Baidu, no answers addressing it.
- try linuxQQ, terrible, still like to windows QQ in 2003
- update deepin-wine, no luck

What I want to do: Install QQ using wine5 and give a desktop label.

Can anyone help me in:

- where to get a new deepin-wine(if one had been made to support wine5)
  or
- how to work around the error of wine black-screening at the end of the installation.

Version:
Ubuntu:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Wine:

```
wine-5.0 (Ubuntu 5.0-3ubuntu1)
```

Thank you!

Comment: What OS & release are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04LTS focal

Comment: Please explain what you mean with the *deepin* references, there are a number of deepin apps in Ubuntu repositories (`apt-cache search deepin` reveals results), but none of the ones you mention.  *Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site  https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic*.

Comment: I mean the project https://github.com/wszqkzqk/deepin-wine-ubuntu which works to export deepin-wine to ubuntu&debain

Comment: PS:I am sorry if this is off-topic. I am having this problem on a ubuntu 20 so I posted it on the ubuntu StackExchange.If it is in the wrong place, I hope that someone will point me to a subexange for it to be posted. Thanks!

Comment: Ubuntu has both *yy* releases (such as 20) and *yy.mm* releases (such as 20.04), and they are different products. A *yy* release such as 20 is *snap* only, and Ubuntu DDE is an *off-topic* re-spin for now, it has it's own support, if & when it becomes a *flavor* it'll be-able to use this site too, but currently it's not reached *flavor* status. Ubuntu Core 20 is however a very different system to your initial question.

Comment: Sorry,I mistyped in my comment.it should be Ubuntu 20.04LTS